# Kafka configure jaas using sasl.jaas.config on kubernetes

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using this helm chart: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka

and these overrides in values.yaml

```
configurationOverrides:
  advertised.listeners: |-
    EXTERNAL://kafka-${KAFKA_BROKER_ID}.host-removed:$((31090 + ${KAFKA_BROKER_ID}))
  listener.security.protocol.map: |-
    PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
  sasl.enabled.mechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-256
  auto.create.topics.enable: false
  inter.broker.listener.name: PLAINTEXT
  sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol: SCRAM-SHA-256
  listener.name.EXTERNAL.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="user" password="password";
```

based on this documentation: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_jaas_broker

(quick summary)

```
Brokers may also configure JAAS using the broker configuration property sasl.jaas.config. The property name must be prefixed with the listener prefix including the SASL mechanism, i.e. listener.name.{listenerName}.{saslMechanism}.sasl.jaas.config. Only one login module may be specified in the config value. If multiple mechanisms are configured on a listener, configs must be provided for each mechanism using the listener and mechanism prefix

listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
    username="admin" \
    password="admin-secret";
```

The problem is that when I start Kafka I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaServer' or 'plaintext.KafkaServer' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

According to the order of precedence, it should use the static jass file if the above config is NOT set.

```
If JAAS configuration is defined at different levels, the order of precedence used is:
```

- Broker configuration property listener.name.{listenerName}.{saslMechanism}.sasl.jaas.config
- {listenerName}.KafkaServer section of static JAAS configuration
- KafkaServer section of static JAAS configuration

The helm chart doesn't support a way to configure this jaas file so using this property seems to be the desired way, I'm just confused as to what is configured incorrectly.

Note: The cluster works fine if I disable all SASL and just use plain text but that's not much good in a real environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've defined 2 listeners: `PLAINTEXT` and `EXTERNAL`. You've mapped both to `SASL_PLAINTEXT`.

Is this really what you wanted to do? or did you want `PLAINTEXT` to not require SASL but just be Plaintext?

- If you really want both to be SASL, then both of them need a JAAS configuration. In your question, I only see a JAAS configuration for EXTERNAL:

  ```
  listener.name.EXTERNAL.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="user" password="password";
  ```

  As you've mapped `PLAINTEXT` to SASL_PLAINTEXT, it also requires a JAAS configuration. You can specify it using for example:

  ```
   listener.name.PLAINTEXT.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="user" password="password";
  ```
- If you wanted your `PLAINTEXT` listener to actually be Plaintext without SASL, then you need to update the listener mapping:

  ```
  listener.security.protocol.map: |-
    PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
  ```

Comment: Your answer helped me get closer to setting up SASL, however in recent versions of kafka (I'm using 2.8.0) it's case sensitive, so `listener.name.EXTERNAL.scram-sha-256` should actually be `listener.name.external.scram-sha-256`